# Get data type without the UI

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008

Is it possible to obtain the datatype of a column without clicking through the UI?

I would like to be able to do...

`SELECT SQLGetTypeInfo(TableName.ColumnName)`

returns `int`

I need this to declare my own variables when debugging parameterized queries. I found `SQLGetTypeInfo` on IBM's website, doesnt work in SSMS 2008.

Comment: I thought `columnproperty()` would produce this, but no--it tells just about everything about a column except the datatype.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put that in a procedure or function if you don't want to call it as query:

```
SELECT DATA_TYPE 
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
where TABLE_NAME = 'TableName'
and COLUMN_NAME = 'ColumnName'
```

Comment: That does it.  I must say, I am a little dissapointed the info is not more specific.  `varchar` rather than `varchar(30)`, worse yet `numeric` rather than the custom type created called `HVCIDdt:numeric(16,0)`.

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey: If you need more info then look at the columns in `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`. There is `NUMERIC_PRECISION` for numbers and `CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH` for character fields.

Comment: Nice.  That gives me 80% of what I need.  Any idea how to lookup a custom type (I dont know if that is the correct terminology)? I mean the prefix "HVCIDdt:".

Comment: It's called a `user-defined type`. Try `SELECT * FROM sys.types where is_user_defined = 1` to see if this holds the info you need